# PyQt5 Automatic drawing from input value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qpainter

I have recently created a widget with `Qpaint`, which I want to pass value to it, at the same time force the `Qpaint` Widget to draw from input values. The idea is to define a data value from a `Qdialog` and pass it to main widget, and pass the value to `Qpaint Widget class`. I would like to have, when user clicks on the button 'Getting values' a dialog widget would appear and insert some `int` values, then pass it to main Widget. from there pass value to correct `class Paint`. Which would draw and display the result. I tried with `Qlabel`, to assign value first to `Qlabel or QlineEdit`,

```
class Button(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
          ---------

        self.value = QtWidgets.QLabel()

           --------
```

Then inside the `paint class` call the value or text of those. then assign it to `Qpaint event`. But seems does not work.'

```
class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = Button()
        self.Value = self.button.value

          ---------

        painter.drawRect(100,100,250,250)     <----- instead of value 250 having self.Value
```

**The code Main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from datainput import *


class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 800, 800))

        self.button = Button()
        self.paint = Paint()

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = Button()
        self.Value = self.button.value

        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)       
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        self.pen = QtGui.QPen()
        self.brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.gray, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.setBrush(self.brush)
        painter.drawRect(100,100,250,250)
        painter.setBrush(QtGui.QBrush())

class Button(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)

        getbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Getting values')
        Alay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        Alay.addWidget(getbutton)

        self.value = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        getbutton.clicked.connect(self.getbuttonfunc)


    def getbuttonfunc(self):
        subwindow=Dinput()
        subwindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        if subwindow.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            self._output = subwindow.valueEdit.text()
            return self.value.setText(self._output)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Input Qdialog code, datainput.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Dinput(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Dinput, self).__init__(parent)

        valuelabel = QtWidgets.QLabel('Input: ')
        self.valueEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()
        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept) 
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.close)

        self.Alay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.Alay.addWidget(valuelabel)
        self.Alay.addWidget(self.valueEdit)

        self.Blay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.Blay.addLayout(self.Alay)
        self.Blay.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(self.Blay)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        super(Dinput, self).closeEvent(event)

    def accept(self):          
        super(Dinput, self).accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Dinput()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Visualization**

[image]

I appreciate any help. Thankssss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`datainput` is irrelevant, your task is only to obtain a number so for space question I will not use it and instead I will use `QInputDialog::getInt()`. Going to the problem, the strategy in these cases where the value can be obtained at any time is to notify the change to the other view through a signal, in the slot that receives the value is to update a variable that stores the value and call update so that it calls when necessary to `paintEvent`, and in the `paintEvent` use the variable that stores the value.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Foo(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 800, 800))

        self.button = Button()
        self.paint = Paint()
        self.button.valueChanged.connect(self.paint.set_size_square)

        self.lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.paint)
        self.lay.addWidget(self.button)

class Paint(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Paint, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.Base)     
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self._size_square = 250

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def set_size_square(self, v):
        self._size_square = v
        self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        brush = QtGui.QBrush( QtCore.Qt.gray, QtCore.Qt.Dense7Pattern)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setBrush(brush)
        r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(100, 100), self._size_square*QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
        painter.drawRect(r)

class Button(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        getbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Getting values')
        Alay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        Alay.addWidget(getbutton)
        self.value = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        getbutton.clicked.connect(self.getbuttonfunc)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def getbuttonfunc(self):
        number, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getInt(self, self.tr("Set Number"),
                                         self.tr("Input:"), 1, 1)
        if ok:
            self.valueChanged.emit(number)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Foo()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @ZarKha It depends on the structure, and since I do not see any in your example I could not tell you where the error is.

Comment: The reason I erased the message, because I found it out. I used this code, under `class another`, I define  `class button` as `self.button = Button()` and with this line code: `self.another.button.valueChanged.connect(self.paint.set_size_square)` . it works. :)